# What physical tool to use to quickly dump firmware?

Tags: firmware, test-equipment, tools

Recently, I managed to take a dump of the firmware and write a modified one using the pins that I marked with red by soldering 4 thin wires to those points. Now, I needed to perform this more than 50 pieces of HC05s. I tried to modify a SOIC-8 programming clip(testing clip), it firstly worked but since I could not hold that in place for minutes, it became a problematic.

What tool would you propose me to achieve this flawlessly? Otherwise, it is really hard to hold it in place and to read/write data without any problem.

[image: HC05]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you seek is a custom fixture with pogo pins. In your case, it might be just a bracket to hold the PCB in place, and the relevant pogo pins (Vcc, GND, and programmer interface)

Comment: Could you please give me some concrete tool examples. I mean by just giving the appropriate size and everything? When I go to electronics shop, I dunno what to tell to the seller.

Comment: In the example I found in [HERE](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-fu2obcPm_Fg/TyBsma85ysI/AAAAAAAAAjQ/qLuQRM1_w6Q/s1600/P1040778.jpg) and [HERE](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HUVr5eFmB5Y/ToYPfimBZ-I/AAAAAAAAAbQ/0vGeu7W_SN4/s1600/P1040772.jpg)  they somehow solved the problem with using pogopins. But, in my example there is one more layer and lots of different components thats stops me from placing pins horizontally.

Comment: The key word is custom. Pogo pins can be purchased from various places, I doubt you will find them in a shop. You will have to figure out which one to choose (Size, tip style) and how to build them into a fixture or adapter.